# A weird question for Tmax(0x7fffffff), why (!x) == x?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void show_case(int x) {
    printf("x + x + 2 = %d\n", x + x + 2);
    printf("!(x + x + 2) = %d\n", !(x + x + 2));
}
int main(){
    show_case(-1);  // the output is 0 & 1
    show_case(0x7fffffff); // the output is 0 & 0;
    return 0;
}
```

hi friends, recently I come across a very weird question when dealing with the datalab in cmu15213.

I simplified the question into the code above.

As we can see, I have implemented a show_case function which can show the (x + x + 2) and !(x + x + 2);
when the argument is -1, the result is as we expected, x+x+2 = 0 and !(x+x+2) = 1.

But when I turn to 0x7fffffff, I found that x+x+2 = 0 and !(x + x + 2) = 0 which is really weird for me.

(Note : the code above was ran on my Ubuntu virtual Machine, while in my windows visual studio, it turns out the ans for 0x7fffffff is 0 & 1 which is as expected).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHOKm.jpg)

Comment: `0x7fffffff` is the maximum value a 32-bit signed integer can represent.   Assuming `int` on your platform is 32-bit, doubling it and adding two produces a result that cannot be represented in an `int`, so causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter that should be an answer.

Comment: @bolov - Big and unsubstantiated assumption underpinned my comment.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming an `int` is 32 bits, `0x7fffffff` is the largest value an `int` can store.  When you then add that value to itself it results in integer overflow which is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When I run this code, I get 0 and 1 for the second case.  This is an example of how undefined behavior can manifest: it works differently on two different systems.

If you change the type of `x` to `unsigned int`, you'll have well defined behavior for wraparound and get 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks! @dbush, I have noticed that because of undefined behavior it turns out to be 0 and 0; But when we turn to unsigned int, it will still cause an unsigned overflow, but why in this case we can get 0 and 1?

Comment: @Xikai_Yang One of the ways undefined behavior can manifest itself is that things appear to work properly.  What *probably* happened in this case is that the overflow essentially wrapped around.  So `0x7fffffff + 0x7fffffff == 0xfffffffe`, and `0xfffffffe + 2 == 0`.  This is exactly what happens in the unsigned case.

Comment: Thanks friend!@dbush So the appropriate way for me to think about it is that when we turned to unsigned int, it just wrapped around and perform as we expected, but when we turn to int, the undefined behavior will cause it to perform differently on different machines, right? So Can I just think that the unsigned int behavior for this case is still an undefined behavior but it just perform well on our machine ?

Comment: @Xikai_Yang The C standard dictates that math on unsigned integers wraps around.  So for example assuming at 32-bit `int` if you add `0xffffffffU + 1` you are guaranteed to get 0.

Comment: @Xikai_Yang Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Because you overflow the the integer. An integer overflow is an Undefined Behaviour.

If you change the parameter to unsigned (which will wrap around) - it will behave as you want

https://godbolt.org/z/Ydp55C

Comment: Thanks! @P__J__  this webpage is pretty useful for understanding the assembly code; But why unsigned int will cause it to behave as we want ?